# Spring - problems loading applicationContext.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

When trying to run project on Tomcat I get:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

My applicationContext.xml file is located under src/main/java/applicationContext.xml.

src/main/java is configured as a source folder in the build path of my Eclipse project, so I'm not understanding why Tomcat is not finding applicationContext.xml?

Comment: Check if the file it's been copied to your WEB-INF/classes on tomcat.

Comment: @RicardoVila doesn't look like it's been copied there

Comment: When running the application in a tomcat the path under `src/main/java/applicationContext.xml` is for sure not on the classpath. Please check what the classpath is and what is on it.

Comment: non java files should reside in `src/main/resource` else they will be ignored.

Comment: @M.Deinum wow that did it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to put it under WEB-INF directory and do like below

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give correct path of the context file, as given below
`<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>`

As BeanDefinitionStoreException is thrown when a BeanFactory encounters an invalid bean definition: e.g. in case of incomplete or contradictory bean metadata.

Reference : http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.2.17.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanDefinitionStoreException.html